# Prevent desktop from switching off when power inverter switches from mains to backup

Tags: power-supply, batteries, capacitor, inverter, ups

I'm using a desktop computer over a [power inverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter) that's connected to a 12V lead acid battery. When the main power supply fails, the inverter switches to battery backup and can power my desktop for 4-6 hours. However, during the transition, my desktop shuts down (the transition time from mains to backup is too large for the desktop).

Is there a circuit / device that'll power the desktop for a few 100 milliseconds till the inverter backup takes over (something like a big capacitor).

**Additional info:**

An alternative is to connect the desktop to a UPS but that'll cost another $70-$100. I'm wondering if there's a cheaper option at a fraction of that.

Some inverters have a "UPS mode" that has a faster switchover time. The downside of this mode is that the operating input voltage range is narrowed i.e. the inverter switches to backup if voltage is outside a narrow range. This isn't a great solution when power quality is low.

Comment: Define `expensive`. A non-expensive UPS could be the trick. In any case, I don't think there's anything that you can do to solve the problem with switching time by adding a device between the computer and inverter.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I've added a price now.

Comment: Define what is "narrow" for you. My UPS can be configured to accept 100V dips.

Comment: You should include a circuit to show how the power is being "switched". Does the battery connect in any way to mains (ACDC to charge it)? Does your computer use DC? I couldn't suggest anything if I don't know the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Put a decent sized cap on the 12V line. Calculate what the estimated load is  by the power supply rating. If your computer is \$(12V)^2/300W = ~2Ω\$  because  \$ V^2/P = R\$. Then calcualte the 1/RC time constant, if you use a big capacitor like 1Farad then you would be protected to 60% of the voltage for 1/(1Farad*2Ω) = 0.5 seconds, you would probably want to be protected to 90% of the voltage so you would really be protected for much less than that but your switching time is probably in the msec, so a 1Farad cap would do great.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frEZTE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I was initially looking for a solution like this, but various mentions on the internet say that the voltage discharge from such a capacitor could be unreliable. Are you sure this is reliable enough to not cause problems for the PC?